# Get DataTables data from both local and REST sourced data

Tags: javascript, promise, datatables

I want to use the jquery pluging datatables and complement local data through an external REST ressource.

My table has to columns, Id and RestCalledValue:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>RestCalledValue</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My js has an object data, which holds my local data:

```
let data = [
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

My datatables initialisation looks like below: i want to give the second column the returned value from the function getRestDataForId (id).

```
$(function () {

    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
            {
                data: "id"
            },
            {
                data: function (row, type, set, meta) {
                    getRestDataForId(row.id);
                },
                defaultContent: "-"
            }

        ]
    });
});


function getRestDataForId(id) {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.title)

}
```

I constructed a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mxhdwfz6/2/

I must be treating the promise wrong. Looking forward for your input!

Comment: Warning: Don't make a call to a URL resource from within a DataTables `columns.data` function. The reason is: each of these functions is processed multiple times per row by DataTables, as it builds its [orthogonal data values](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). You should be able to confirm that for yourself by looking at the network tab of your browser's admin tools, where you will see all the duplicate calls. So, instead, collect this data outside of DataTables.

Comment: Yeah, ive notived that - what i do now is: 
0. prepare my data object with default data for the data to complement
1. after building the table I make a call to supplement my original data object
2. invalidate the column containg the data.